# Resizing all windows of all running applications

Tags: macos, resize, window, applescript

I am attempting to write an applescript script that will allow me to resize all windows of all running applications whenever I choose (I currently use [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/), but find that it is glitchy at times, so I want to "re-invent" it)
I have been following some applescripting tutorials and have come up with the following code to do so, but it is buggy:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set rect to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

property excludedApplicationNames : {"Finder"}
tell application "System Events"
    say "a"
    repeat with theProcess in processes
        say "b"
        if background only of theProcess is false then
            say "c"
            set theProcessName to name of theProcess as string
            if theProcessName is not in excludedApplicationNames then
                say theProcessName
                tell application theProcess
                    set bounds of windows of process theProcess to rect
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
say "done"
```

The problem is that when this code encounters my only terminal window (with several open tabs), it error: `System Events got an error: Can’t set application (item 2 of every process) to {0, 0, 1280, 900}.System Events got an error: Can’t set application (item 2 of every process) to {0, 0, 1280, 900}.`

Changing `tell application theProcess` to `tell application theProcessName` doesn't help (same error), and neither does changing it to `tell application "System Events"` (Error: `System Events got an error: Can’t make item 2 of every process into type integer.`)

Interestingly, this works as expected:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set rect to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with theWindow in windows
        set bounds of theWindow to rect
    end repeat
end tell
```

So I'm very confused.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: I've found `tell application "Finder" to set window 1's bounds to {0, 0, 600, 600}` to be buggy as well. It works well for some apps, like Finder and iTunes, but [it doesn't redraw shadows for Safari](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uggRs.jpg). And Preview has no AppleScript support at all, so its windows can't be resized by AppleScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set {0, 0, dtw, dth} to bounds of window of desktop
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with p in (processes where background only is false)
        tell p
            if name is not in {"Finder"} then
                set position of windows to {0, 0}
                set size of windows to {dtw, dth}
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

- Took about 3 seconds on my Mac
- Maximizes Terminal windows to fill the screen (except for the 4px area taken up by Dock)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set dtb to bounds of window of desktop
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    bundle identifier of processes where background only is false
end tell
repeat with bid in result
    tell application id bid
        try
            if name is not in {"Finder"} then
                set (bounds of windows where visible is true) to dtb
            end if
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
```

- Took about 0.3 seconds on my Mac
- Doesn't work with all applications like Preview or Reeder
- Uses bundle identifiers because a few applications have different process and application names
- Resizes Terminal windows so that they have a few pixels empty space above and below them

I use this script to maximize windows:

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set dtb to bounds of window of desktop
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        if name is in {"Terminal"} then
            error
        else
            set bounds of window 1 to dtb
        end if
    end tell
on error
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
        try
            click (button 1 of window 1 where subrole is "AXZoomButton")
        end try
    end tell
end try
```

In many applications that don't have basic AppleScript support the zoom button also maximizes windows to fill the screen.

Comment: I tested each of the three scripts above and the first one worked the best and maximized the windows of all applications I could throw at it. Used along with ControlPlane it's a treat to not have to worry about windows anymore when connecting, disconnecting external display!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This one take the size of the dock into account. I have mine on the right side of the monitor, but it should be easy to modify to accommodate the dock being on the bottom.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set dtb to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    set dockDimentions to size in list 1
    set dockWidth to item 1 of dockDimentions
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    bundle identifier of processes where background only is false
end tell

repeat with bid in result
    tell application id bid
        try
            if name is not in {"Finder", "System Preferences", "Notepad", "Terminal", "Activity Monitor"} then
                set x to item 1 of dtb
                set y to item 2 of dtb
                set w to (item 3 of dtb) - dockWidth
                set h to item 4 of dtb
                set (bounds of windows) to {x, y, w, h}
            end if
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

This eventually did the trick for me:

```
property blacklist : {"Finder", "Preview", "Console", "AppleScript Editor", "Spotify", "TaskCoach"}
property buttonApps : {"LyX", "Eclipse"}
property buttonMaps : {{name:"LyX", Button:1, pname:"lyx"}, {name:"Eclipse", Button:2, pname:"eclipse"}}

tell application "Finder" to set theBounds to bounds of window of desktop

tell application "System Events"
    set bids to bundle identifier of processes where background only is false
end tell

repeat with bid in bids
    tell application id bid
        if name is not in blacklist then
            set appName to name as string
            if name is "Terminal" then
                set newBounds to {0, 0, (item 3 of theBounds) - 10, item 4 of theBounds}
                repeat with theWindow in windows
                    if visible of theWindow is true then
                        say appName
                        set bounds of theWindow to newBounds
                    end if
                end repeat
            else if name is not in buttonApps then
                repeat with theWindow in windows
                    if visible of theWindow is true then
                        set bounds of theWindow to theBounds
                    end if
                end repeat
            else if name is in buttonApps then
                -- get the buttonNumber
                repeat with buttonApp in buttonMaps
                    if (name of buttonApp as string) is appName then
                        set theButton to Button of buttonApp
                    end if
                end repeat
                tell application "System Events"
                    repeat with theProcess in (processes where bundle identifier is bid)
                        try
                            tell theProcess to tell window 1 to click button theButton
                        end try
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Note that "Spotify" and "Task Coach" are blacklisted because I am not able to resize them by:

1. setting the window bounds
2. clicking on the green button
3. clicking on "Window">"Zoom" in the menu bar
4. using the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut that I had mapped it to.

If anyone is able to come up with a better solution, I'm all ears